# AddRange() and LINQ copying issue

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sum

I currently have a method which is quite simple and calculates a list of CurveValue (custom object), the issue I have is I need to calculate the parameter and pass a decimal back without actually changing the parameter.

I tried to AddRange() into a new object so the parameter curve would not be affected but it seems the reference still exists and after the ForEach() is performed both curve, and curveA have changed.

I'm assuming it is still referenced but is there an easy way of doing this without enumerating through the parameter curve and adding it to curveA?

```
public decimal Multiply(List<CurveValue> curve, decimal dVal)
{
    List<CurveValue> curveA = new List<CurveValue>();
    curveA.AddRange(curve);

    curveA.ForEach(a => a.Value = decimal.Round(a.Value, 4) * dVal);

    return Sum(curveA);
}

public decimal Sum(List<CurveValue> curveA)
{
    return curveA.Sum(x => x.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use [the Sum method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549046.aspx) like so:

```
public decimal Multiply(IEnumerable<CurveValue> curve, decimal dVal)
{
    return curve.Sum(a => decimal.Round(a.Value, 4) * dVal);
}
```

**Update**

Providing another implementation that passes through to the existing Sum method:

```
public decimal Multiply(IEnumerable<CurveValue> curve, decimal dVal)
{
    IEnumerable<CurveValue> curveA = curve.Select(c => new Curve { Value = decimal.Round(c.Value, 4) * dVal });
    return Sum(curveA);
}

public decimal Sum(IEnumerable<CurveValue> curveA)
{
    return curveA.Sum(x => x.Value);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, updated my code. Sum is just a method which does the obvious. I need to calculate each CurveValue object individually, then sum these. The operation side is fine, I just have no idea why curve is being updated when the operation is being performed on curveA.

Comment: @nik0lias CurveA contains references to exactly the same objects in curve, so you are still dealing with the same objects when you change them (in curveA.ForEach(...)).

Comment: Is there any easy way of copying curve to curveA and removing the references? Or is it a case of enumerating and creating new objects and then adding these to curveA?

Comment: @nik0lias I am unsure why you wish to do this as opposed to my method above, but yes you'll have to create a new instance of CurveValue if you wish to mutate it and not have this affect the curve items in `curve`.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't see the update. I went with the select approach and it seems obvious when I think about it, as select doesn't hard copy. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

As you're using a List collection, you're able to use the Select extension method. This method provides a parameter where you define a transformation function for each element on your list and returns an IEnumerable where T is the type you specify on your function.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

This may be a bit old-school, but why are you copying the range at all?

You could just iterate over curve, and put the calculated value into a result list, then sum the values up.

```
List<CurveValue> curveA = new List<CurveValue>();        
curve.ForEach(a => curveA.Add(new CurveValue {Value = decimal.Round(a.Value, 4) * dVal });          

return Sum(curveA);
```

Sorry for not checking the code, I'm on my netbook here. I hope you get what I mean.